# RHEL7 PAM Password Length based on UID

Tags: rhel, security, password, pam

I'm trying to configure password policy based on different UIDs.
So for example:

```
- UID 1000-1999 would have Password minimum lenght of 15
- UID 2000-2999 would have Password minimum lenght of 20
...
```

How would this be configured? The /etc/security/pwquality.conf does not seem to have separation for UIDs, so I'm assuming that I would have to use /etc/pam.d/system-auth and/or /etc/pam.d/password-auth, but I haven't managed to find a working configuration.

Comment: not sure if it is at all possible, most likely you would need to make use of your own pam module to take into consideration the uid